# NullReferenceException: как исключить ошибку?

Tags: c#, unity3d, null

Ошибка:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
Texturename.FirstTree.DrawFirstTree () (at Assets/TerrainTools/StampToolExtended/LoadScript/FirstTree.cs:74)
```

Есть класс :

```
namespace marijnz.EditorCoroutines
{
    public class PlacementObjects : EditorWindow
    {
        ...
        public Terrain[] TerrainList = new Terrain[0];
        ...
    }
}
```

Как в другом классе проверить, что TerrainList не пустой и  то что он существует?

```
public class FirstTree  {

    public void DrawFirstTree() {
        marijnz.EditorCoroutines.PlacementObjects temp = marijnz.EditorCoroutines.PlacementObjects._windowPlacementObj;
        ...
        if(temp.TerrainList.Count() > 0) { //возникает ошибка тут
            if(temp.TerrainList[0]) {
                LoadTreeIcons(temp.TerrainList[0]);
                LoadTextureIcons(temp.TerrainList[0]);
            }
        }
        ...
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну, вы же этот список откуда-то берёте - так и проверяйте перед обращением к полю с помощью  `if([что-то] != null)`. При этом ошибка у вас, судя по всему, не в наличии листа, а в наличии самого объекта в `_windowPlacementObj`

Answer (score 1):

```
public class FirstTree  {

    public void DrawFirstTree() {
        marijnz.EditorCoroutines.PlacementObjects temp = ...;

        if( temp != null ) { // <- проверка того, что объект на что-то ссылается
            if(temp.TerrainList.Count() > 0) {
                ...
        }
        ...
```